# Task is only run once

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

My program is basicly an installation program it needs to copy files from inside the jar to outside without disturbing the GUI. So I ran everything in a task but the task doesnt run more than once.

This is the button (FXML):

```
<Button fx:id="button1" onAction="#startInstall">
```

and this is in the controller:

```
@FXML
public Button button1;

public void startInstall() {
    if (!working) {
        working = true;
        installoption = true;
        advanced = false;
        System.out.println("pressed install");
        new Thread(normalInstall).start();
        System.out.println("after task call");
        return;
    }
}
```

and this is the task:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Task normalInstall = new Task<Void>() {

    public void normalInstall() {

        setGUI(null,"Getting package info.");
        JSONObject info = getInfo();
        System.out.println(info);
        String mpmUUID = (String) info.get("UUID");
        setGUI(null,"Setting up folders.");
        --SNIP--
        deleteTemp(mpmUUID);
        setGUI(null,"Install has finished.");
        working = false;
        return;
    }


    @Override public Void call() {
        if(installoption == true) {
            if (advanced == true) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
                chooser.setDialogTitle("choose install directory.");
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

                if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("directory choosen: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
                    customPathBool = true;
                    customPath = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No Selection ");
                }
            }
            JSONObject info = getInfo();
            String uuid = (String) info.get("UUID");
            String profile = getProfileList(getProfiles(),uuid);
            Integer installerversion = Integer.parseInt((String)(info.get("mapVersion")));
            Integer installedversion = null;
            if (profile != null) {
                installedversion = getProfileVersion(getProfiles(),profile);
            }
            if (profile == null) {
                normalInstall();
                return null;
            } else {
                int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                        null,
                        "It seems that this map is already installed.\n Do you want to reset the map?",
                        "Map already installed",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    if (installerversion < installedversion) {
                        int b = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                                null,
                                "You have an outdated version of the installer.\n Do you want to continue?",
                                "Older version",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                        if (b == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                            unInstall();
                            normalInstall();
                            return null;
                        } else {
                            setGUI(null,"Install canceled.");
                            return null;
                        }
                    } else {
                        unInstall();
                        normalInstall();
                        return null;
                    }
                } else {
                    setGUI(null,"Install canceled.");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        } else {
            unInstall();
            return null;
        }
    }
};
```

And here is the console:

```
    {"MCVersion":"1.11","pathOptions":null,"pathWorld":"world.zip","name":"uninstall test","mapVersion":"1","icon":"TNT","UUID":"5b2e55ed-bb5c-48e0-bbf5-49a7851453bb","pathPack":"pack.zip"}
pressed install
after task call
[a63d52eda9384a7ca1607d8ea0b2fe53, 44d01181eae635d31f2cefe5e1f75cd4, e0e96e422659dfdc1ad16d53a37ee618]
a63d52eda9384a7ca1607d8ea0b2fe53
--SNIP--
finished creating profile
pressed install
after task call
```

I pressed the button 5 times. the first time it did what it was supposed to do.
The second time everything is run before and after the task but didnt do the task itself. The 3 times it didnt do anything. I have no clue what is going on.

Comment: you just bumped in your entire code base. You really think someone would read through all of that ? Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Shashwat I just did, thanks for the tags and the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API documentation:

The Task class defines a one-time object that cannot be reused. If you need a reusable Worker object, use the Service class. [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

To run the task each time you will need a new instance of it:

```
NormalInstallTask normalInstall = new NormalInstallTask ();
new Thread(normalInstall).start();
```

Or create a service and start it...

Comment: Thanks, I just kinda asumed that tasks are reusable. I guess not.